# Android Layout and Image Buttons and Grey Border

Tags: android, android-layout

I have seen a few threads about this, but nothing exactly want I was looking for.

I have an image button that lays ontop a black background.

The image buttons have a huge grey border. I have tried to turn off border, and make the border black... It's not working out. I just want the buttons to be on the screen with a transparent background and expand a little wider if possible. NO GREY.

Any clue?

[image]

```
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    style="@android:style/ButtonBar" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/map" android:id="@+id/ImageButton1" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </ImageButton>

    <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/list" android:id="@+id/ImageButton2" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </ImageButton>

    <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/share" android:id="@+id/ImageButton3" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </ImageButton>

</LinearLayout> </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: could you send a screenshot of what you want it to look like and what its looking like now?

Comment: I added an image. Sorry, I didn't know I could do that. Can you see the issue? I would prefer that my buttons were a little wider and the grey completely gone. Anotheroption would be if I could put all the buttons on one bar accross the bottom.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I know what you're talking about. Give this a try. You want to include `android:background="@null"` to get rid of that grey outline.

For instance, in your layout where you declare the ImageButton:

```
<ImageButton android:background="@null" ...>
    .
    .
    .
</ImageButton>
```

Comment: Yes, it should get rid of the light grey background around the three buttons, not sure about the darker grey one. You'll need to post your layout xml file for me to get a better look if you want further assistance.

Comment: What also works is setting the background transparent. android:background="#FF000000"

Comment: Thanks. I will give that a try later today. Do you know if the grey border will also disappear?

Comment: If you want your button to stretch the entire width, I would highly recommend looking into .9.png files if you already haven't. It will make adjusting button sizes a lot easier. More info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch